# Close modal on click button react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a modal that shown on a button click and the modal is fetched from another component using prop.

In the modal there is a button to close the modal, How to close the modal onclick the button. I have tried but doesn't worked.

```
//InvalidUser

const InvalidUser = (props) => (
<Modal
    visible={props.display}
    animationType="slide"
    onRequestClose={() => console.log('closed')}
>
    <View style={styles.modalBox}>
        <View style={{width: 300}}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
                {props.data}
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                    this.closeModal()
                }>
                <Text style={styles.buttonOk}>Ok</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
</Modal>
);
```

//Login

```
export default class LoginFirst extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        email: '',
        modalVisible: false
    };
}

nextBtn = () => {
    let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

    if (this.state.email !== '') {
        if (reg.test(this.state.email) === false) {

        }
        else {
            this.setState({modalVisible: true});
        }
    }
}

render() {
    let notRegistered = this.state.email+' is not recognized as a registered user. Please contact us for further assistance.';

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scroller}>
                <View
                    style={styles.inputSection}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.label}>Email Address:</Text>
                    <View style={styles.section}>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.icon}
                            source={require('../../../../assets/user.png')}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='johnsmith@gmail.com'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={() =>
                            this.nextBtn()
                        }
                    >
                            <Text style={styles.next}>Next</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            <InvalidUserModal
                data={notRegistered}
                display={this.state.modalVisible}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

The above code is perfectly displaying the modal, but I cannot close the modal. Is there any way to close.

Please have a look into below image.

[image: Modal]

Comment: Where is closeModal() function ?

Comment: I have no idea where to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from parent component, create closeModal function and pass it to InvalidUserModal

```
closeModal = () => {
  this.setState({modalVisible: false});
}

<InvalidUserModal
   data={notRegistered}
   display={this.state.modalVisible}
   closeModal={this.closeModal}
/>
```

and call it inside InvalidUserModal on press the button

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={props.closeModal}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonOk}>Ok</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: not it is showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at Object.onPress`

Comment: @JithinVarghese sorry, didn't notice that you're using function component,just change this.props to props

Comment: does'nt work the above change, can you please check.

Comment: I have placed `console.log` inside `closeModal`. But it is not showing.

Comment: check carefully, you probably have a typo somewhere, notice props.closeModal doen't have parentheses

Comment: I have removed the parentheses, but still `console.log` not showing.

Comment: @JithinVarghese sorry, forgot to pass closeModal to InvalidUserModal lol, check it again

Answer (score 1):

For parent, pass the `closeModal` method as a props to your component

```
  class LoginFirst extends Component {
      closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({modalVisible: false});
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <InvalidUserModal
            data={notRegistered}
            display={this.state.modalVisible}
            closeModal={this.closeModal}
          />
        )
      }
    }
```

For your modal component

```
<Modal
  visible={props.display}
  animationType="slide"
  onRequestClose={() => console.log('closed')}
>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.closeModal}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonOk}>Ok</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Modal>
```